# I need to display input items in an array inside paragraph but items disappear after submission and display

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

The goal is to add items into the input box and display them in the paragraph below it.
But page disappears after the items are displayed.
I need the page to stay the way it is and not disappear.
Bellow I included the css and the javascript inside the same HTML file because it is easier to copy-paste

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
h1{
color: Crimson;
}
h3 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: gray;
}
#sentence{
width:300px;
height: 200px;
border: 2px dashed darkred;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Show Room</h1>

<form onsubmit="memory()">
 
 <p>Add items to display bellow</p>
 
 <textarea id="box" name="box" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="example: frame picture beach ..."></textarea>
 
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
<h3>Display</h3>
<p id="sentence"></p>

<script>

var items = [];

function memory() {
  boxvalue = document.getElementById('box').value;
  items.push(boxvalue);  
   document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = items;
  return false;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the return value from `memory` to stop the form from submitting, you need to explicitly return it in the `onsubmit` attribute.

```
onsubmit="return memory()"
```

However, it is better to use `addEventListener` and `event.preventDefault()` instead rather than inline event handlers.

You can implement this like so:

```js
// remove the onsubmit attribute on the form first
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    memory();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
h1{
color: Crimson;
}
h3 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: gray;
}
#sentence{
width:300px;
height: 200px;
border: 2px dashed darkred;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Show Room</h1>

<form onsubmit="memory()">
 
 <p>Add items to display bellow</p>
 
 <textarea id="box" name="box" rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="example: frame picture beach ..."></textarea>
 
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
<h3>Display</h3>
<p id="sentence"></p>

<script>

var items = [];

function memory() {
  event.preventDefault();
  boxvalue = document.getElementById('box').value;
  items.push(boxvalue);  
   document.getElementById("sentence").innerHTML = items.toString();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for putting it all together  I appreciate

Comment: @mmirbekian This answer uses [window.event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event), which is deprecated. Do not use this.